# c# close winforms from another winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have form 1 and form 2.  In form 1, I have 4 button which button 1 and 2 is use to open form 2 by provide the form 2 with specific name which is form2A and form2B.  Button 3 and 4 is use to close the opened form base on the form name.  How I can close the form2A when click button 3 but not close the form2B?

```
public static List<Form> forms = new List<Form>();
```

Form Open

```
TagItem.TagItemInfo tagItemInfo = new TagItem.TagItemInfo(symbol_id);
tagItemInfo.Name = symbol_id.ToString();
TagList.forms.Add(tagItemInfo);
tagItemInfo.Show();
```

Form close

```
if(TagList.forms.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach(Form frm in TagList.forms)
            {
                if(frm.Name == o.SymbolID.ToString())
                {
                    frm.Dispose();
                    frm.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

My system can open as many as form which will specify a name for it.

Comment: Store the `Form2 form2A` reference somewhere (a Field, a handler class etc.) assign the instance when you create one, then `form2A.Close();` when needed. Better check for `null` or `.IsDisposed` before. So maybe `form2A?.Close();`

Comment: I store in a List<form>.  And when click the close button then foreach the list and check the form name match then perform form.close() but it not work

Comment: Post that code then. If you want to use some kind of list, checking a Form's name, you already have [Application.OpenForms()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.openforms) that keeps that list for you. I suggested a more direct approach since you have just a couple of Forms to handle and maybe you want to use those reference for something else during the life-time of the instances.

Comment: @Jimi I have add my code in the question.

Comment: What is o in o.SymbolID.ToString()?

Comment: @o_weisman it is just a unique ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define Form2A and Form2B as 2 different vars:

```
private Form2 _form2a, _form2b;

//open Form 2A with Windowtext "Form 2A"
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _form2a = new Form2 { Text="Form 2A" };
    _form2a.Show();
}

//open Form 2B with Windowtext "Form 2B"
private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _form2b = new Form2 { Text="Form 2B" };
    _form2b.Show();
}

//close Form 2A
private void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _form2a.Close();
}

//close Form 2B
private void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _form2b.Close();
}
```